# How to implement a selectable array struct in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I would like to implement an array struct which can mark a single element is able to be as selected. Thus, that element can be easily accessed.

I am creating a wrapper class around `Array` struct. Is there any good way to delegate `Array` methods to my `SelectableArray`'s internal array?

Or is there other better way to do it?

```
class SelectableArray<Element: Comparable> {
    let array = Array<Element>()
    private var selectedIndex: Int? = .None

    var selectedElement: Element? {
        guard let index = selectedIndex else {
            return .None
        }
        return array[index]
    }

    func select(index: Int) {
        selectedIndex = array.indices.contains(index) ? index : .None
    }

    func select(element: Element) {
        selectedIndex = array.indexOf(element)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code of what you currently have, so that it is easier to understand what you are trying to implement.

Comment: Probably not. You'd have to write your own methods. You can, however, subclass `NSArray`. Or you can try to `extension` the `Array` struct.

Comment: Have added the code, but not yet fully implemented. Need to add the logic to update the index when the array change.

Comment: The problem is that when I would like to modify the array I need to have code like `selectableArray.array.append(...)`. I would like to just `selectableArray.append(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an `append` method for your wrapper class and change `array` to a `var` from a `let`:

```
class SelectableArray<Element: Comparable> {
    var array = Array<Element>()
    private var selectedIndex: Int? = .None

    // other functions...

    func append(element: Element) {
        self.array.append(element)
    }
}
```

Comment: How to delegate all `Array` method to my `Wrapper`? I would like this class behaviour exactly like vanilla `Array` with the additional ability to keep track of selected element.

Comment: You can't! Arrays in Swift are structs so you can't inherit it. If you extend the struct, you are not allowed to add new stored property (`selectedIndex`). Implement the ones you use often, like `append` and `subscript`. The rest must be access through the `array` property

Comment: I should qualify that by say if you are willing to go back to ObjectiveC, you can inherit from `NSMutableArray` and add `selectedIndex` as an associated object